# Calling a function once the dom has finished loading durandal

Tags: javascript, html, dom, durandal

I have got a function which I am calling at onchange event. I am taking the value from that function and displaying that value on some other location in my view.
This is my code

*ViewModel Code*

```
       DisplayDetails = function(data, event)
     {
    var id = event.target.id;
     var input = document.getElementById(id).value;
    alert(input);

    var div = document.getElementById('childcontainer');

        if(div == null)
        {
          return;
        }
        else
        {
          div.innerHTML = input.value;

        }


}
```

*View Code*

```
<input  class="form-control" name="FName" type="text" id="FName" placeholder="First Name"  data-bind=" value: FName , event: { keyup: blockSpecialCharAndNumeric }, event: { change: DisplayDetails }"  >
```

My function is called and I get the value but while displaying I get **div = null** since my function is called before the dom has finished loading. I know in durandal we have **composition.addBindingHandler** for this. I went through the documentation but not sure how to use it in my scenerio. Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Durandal features [lifecycle callbacks](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html), which are called at various points of your view model's lifecycle, including the point at which your view has been composed into the DOM.

Try implementing *compositionComplete* and accessing your "childcontainer" element from there. At this point in time, your element will be part of the DOM. You'll probably want to modify your event handler so it only executes after *compositionComplete*.